# What are the benefits/purposes of cmake?

Tags: makefile, cmake

I decided to look into cmake, but after reading about it my first through is: if i have to write a cmake config file, why don't I just write a makefile?

motivation:
I was thinking of replacing Eclipse as my C/C++ editor with Qt Creator, which includes cmake as a default makefile generator.

Comment: This looks off-topic to me, opinion-based.

Comment: It's certainly nothing that needs to be C/C++ tagged.

Comment: `make` works on a much lower level. CMake figures out a lot dependencies. CMake is to `make` like C is to assembler.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The primary advantage of CMake is that it's cross-platform (both in the sense of OSes and buildsystems in general). A *single* CMake config file can generate a native buildsystem for make (Makefiles), Visual Studio (Visual Studio soultions & projects), ninja, NMake, Code::Blocks, Eclipse, KDEdevelop, ... And it generates a *native* buildsystem for that tool, so that developers using the buildsystem work the way they're used to.

Even for single-platform projects, CMake offers higher-level mechanisms like external library detection and configuration (i.e. automatically setting up the defines, include directories and link files for working with a 3rd party library), support for generating installation (and packaging), integration with the CTest test utility and so on.

CMake also abstracts some compiler-specifics like "which flags to pass to make a shared library" or "how to enable PIC or interprocedural optimisation." So you can generate a makefile for gcc, Clang or the Sun CC compiler without necessarily caring about their interface details.

Comment: Some of the features you describe in the second paragraph are also available with plain `make` if you use implicit rules and `pkg-config`.